# PHP GD - performance/time difference between output and save

Tags: php, performance, gd

Using php and gd - what's better for performance or time to execute between:

Outputting image

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
imagepng($image);
```

Or saving the image to the server (to either local server or Amazon s3)

```
imagepng($image, 'new_image.png');
```

Comment: performance for what? Is this going to be served up to more than one user? In that case, save to file, so you don't waste years of cpu time regenerating the same image over and over again. Will it only ever be seen once? then send directly, it'll be a waste of time to send to s3 or write to disk, just to delete it again afterwards.

Comment: It will be served to many customers so yes it will be repeated over and over

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there will be no difference in the time it takes to generate the image data, because it will be the same in both cases.

However, when you save the image to a local disk the operation will probably terminate a lot quicker than when the data has to be sent to a client browser somewhere in the world.

However, the point of PHP is to present something in a browser, so I guess you will show the stored file anyway, negating any benefit in speed you gained from storing the image.

So, if you want so show the image in both cases, I guess it would be better to output the image directly from the PHP script.

On the other hand, if you use the image more than once, then you should save it, and use the saved version because generating the image itself takes time in PHP.

If you want to generate once, and use many times, you could use this piece of PHP code:

```
<?php
// this is where it is stored
$filename = 'my_image.png';

// test if file exists
if (!file_exists($filename))
{
  // if does not exist, make it
  <... your code for making the image ...>
  // store to disk
  imagepng($image,$filename);
  // image is not needed anymore
  imagedestroy($image);
}  

// header
header('Content-Type: image/png');
// get file from the disk
readfile($filename);
?>
```

Simply delete the image from disk if you have changed it and you want to regenerate it. This is a very basic example, you can build on it depending on your needs.

Comment: Thank you. Yes the image will be served many many times. But like you say I will be showing the image in both cases, so I guess it's better to take the extra time the first time to generate it?

Comment: Well yes, if you don't generate it, it won't exist. Once it exists you can simply serve the file straight from the disk. I'll add a bit of PHP code to my answer.